# One UITableViewCell is controlling others

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Does anyone know what's happening here? I've configured a `UITableView` with `CollectionViewCells`, and each of these cells is supposed to operate independently of each other, yet when I swipe one it controls another cell which is 3 cells underneath it.

Tried to reconfigure my `UITableViewCells` and the `CollectionViewCells`. But I'm not exactly sure what to do

```
//TableView controler


import UIKit
import CardsLayout
import CHIPageControl

class eventsFeed: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{


    // Global Variable
    var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        tableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.minX, y: self.view.bounds.minY+UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height))

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        self.view.addSubview(tableView)

        tableView.register(TableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "TableViewCell")
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: TableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        return cell
    }
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
    {
        return 430.0;//Choose your custom row height
    }



}


//CollectionViewCell for TableView

import UIKit
import CardsLayout

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {



    var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)


        let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.horizontal

        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y:0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 410.0), collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.center = CGPoint(x: 187.5, y: 180)
        collectionView.collectionViewLayout = CardsCollectionViewLayout()
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true
        collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell")
        collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        self.addSubview(collectionView)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    }
    var colors: [UIColor]  = [
        UIColor(red: 237, green: 37, blue: 78),
        UIColor(red: 249, green: 220, blue: 92),
        UIColor.blue,
        UIColor(red: 1, green: 25, blue: 54),
        UIColor(red: 255, green: 184, blue: 209),
        UIColor(red: 237, green: 37, blue: 78),
        UIColor(red: 249, green: 220, blue: 92)
        ]

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath)
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 12.0
        cell.backgroundColor = colors[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return colors.count
    }
}
```

Video of issue: https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/btcok4/does_anyone_know_whats_happening_here_ive/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cells are reused. That means that you have to choose different strategy of working with them.

Save somewhere current state for each table view cell (for example in structs in an array) and then configure cell based on this state in `cellForRowAt` delegate's method.